# Can Someone Help me with Writing to a Log - Error: Bound Method?

Tags: python

Any help is appreciated. I was able to get it to print to the log, but I received the bound method error. I think it has something to do with my + str in my exception handling.

```
else:
     Leibniz_object = MarshallHomework6.Pi_LeibnizClass(10)
     logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',
                         format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                         level=logging.INFO)
                msg1 = 'The circumference of circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_circumference)()
                logging.info(msg1)
                msg2 = 'The area of a circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_area)()
                logging.info(msg2)
                msg3 = 'The volume of a circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_volume)()
                logging.info(msg3)
                msg4 = 'The surface area of a circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_surfacearea)()
                logging.info(msg4)
                ending()
```

Comment: What's up with those weird unicode quotation marks?

Comment: whats going on with your code? you have an else statement before if on line 9. You should also properly indent your code.

Comment: Let me edit. It didn't paste correctly. I'm new to this. Sorry.

Comment: Tecia, welcome to Stack Overflow. It helps us help you if you can provide as much context as possible when asking a question -- for example, if you're getting an error, it's very helpful to indicate which line of the code you've posted is generating that error message. It also helps if your code is syntactically correct, and the code shown here has some indentation problems that would prevent it from running. If all of those `msg... = ...` statements are part of the `else` block, they all need to be out-dented to line up with the `logging` statement.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing the code of the `MarshallHomework6.Pi_LeibnizClass` class it's hard to be sure, but in statements like this...

```
msg1 = 'The circumference of circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_circumference)()
```

...it looks like you've misplaced a set of parentheses. To call a function or method, you write `object.methodname()`. If you omit the parentheses, or if they don't immediately follow the function name, you aren't calling the function. Instead of the function return value, you get a reference to the function itself (which, when you convert it to a string, yields something like `<bound method Pi_LeibnizClass.get_volume of <__main__.Pi_LeibnizClass object at 0x7f0cd85cde50`). There are valid use cases for this, but that's probably not what you want.

I think you meant to write:

```
msg1 = 'The circumference of circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_circumference())
```

And similarly:

```
msg2 = 'The area of a circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_area())
msg3 = 'The volume of a circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_volume())
msg4 = 'The surface area of a circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_surfacearea())
```

Here's the code I used to test things out (with a dummy class, since I
don't know what the `MarshallHomework6` module looks like):

```
import logging

class Pi_LeibnizClass:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    def get_circumference(self):
        return 1

    def get_area(self):
        return 2

    def get_volume(self):
        return 3

    def get_surfacearea(self):
        return 4


Leibniz_object = Pi_LeibnizClass(10)
logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO)
msg1 = 'The circumference of circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_circumference())
logging.info(msg1)
msg2 = 'The area of a circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_area())
logging.info(msg2)
msg3 = 'The volume of a circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_volume())
logging.info(msg3)
msg4 = 'The surface area of a circle is: ' + str(Leibniz_object.get_surfacearea())
logging.info(msg4)
```

This outputs:

```
2021-07-23 16:59:47,379 INFO: The circumference of circle is: 1
2021-07-23 16:59:47,379 INFO: The area of a circle is: 2
2021-07-23 16:59:47,379 INFO: The volume of a circle is: 3
2021-07-23 16:59:47,379 INFO: The surface area of a circle is: 4
```